# OpenCV: Speeding up KLT tracks and Harris corners extraction

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking

I am using OpenCV's goodfeaturesToTrack along with subpixel refinement of the corners found & Lucas Kanade tracker? 
Do you have any suggestions for alternatives that can achieve higher speeds?

Comment: Can you explain the application? What do you want to do with the tracked features?